# Distributing ruby application as standalone in linux and windows

Tags: ruby, deployment, software-distribution

I have developed ruby application (desktop application) on version 1.9.1 with few gems(qtbindings). Now i would like to distribute my application to users as stand alone.I would like to distribute my application as stand alone in linux too.  What is the best gem/script for doing this job.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this link](https://github.com/rdp/ruby_tutorials_core/wiki/ruby-talk-faq#wiki-ruby_to_exe) where several options are offered to distribute a Ruby script as a "native" executable.

Keep in mind that Linux users usually do not need this, `bundle install` and `ruby myscript.rb` is enough on those systems.

Comment: That's quite the assumption for Linux. There's just as much need for a stand-alone distributable on Linux as any other platform.

Answer (score -3):

First define "stand alone," please.  If you mean "I assume that you will have a suitable Ruby interpreter installed and on the PATH" then on Linux and other Unix-alikes it should suffice to add a shebang line at the top:

```
#! /bin/env ruby
```

and set the executable bits in the permission mask.

If you mean that your users may not have Ruby installed, and you don't want to make it a prerequisite, that's a much taller order and I have no advice.